# Can I detect whether a pipe's reader end is being read?

Tags: c, pipe, stdin

I have a **pipe**; the reader end is connected to a child process's STDIN, and the parent process has the writer end. Is there a way for the parent to detect whether or not its child is actually reading (syscall `read(2)`) the pipe?

The parent's logic and child's environment can be modified. The child process is a black box; it can be anything, so we can not modify child's inner logic. We can not send a "probe" to the pipe, such as writing a single char on it and waiting until it is slurped.

Let me clarify it by a (Python) code snippet:

```python
reader, writer = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
  os.close(writer)
  os.dup2(reader, sys.stdin.fileno())
  os.execvp('anycommand', ['anycommand', 'arg'])
  # executing anycommand which read()s STDIN somewhen and unknown times
else:
  os.close(reader)
  while True:
    while not is_pipe_being_read(pid, reader, writer):
      print "not reading... doing parent businnes"
      time.sleep(1)
    print "reading! stop doing parent businnes, feed data depending on parent businnes so far"
    os.write(writer, "some data")
```

Comment: You should open the output of your parent process with the `O_NONBLOCK` option and then check how many bytes are written in a loop.  As you can realize, this is therefore a programming question (off-topic here).

Comment: `fcntl(.., F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK)` should do it!

Comment: Since this has now been migrated to a programming Q&A site, can you please add a language tag so we know what language to write our code samples in?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you want to know whether the child process is currently stuck in a blocking `read` call? If so, `ptrace` is your best bet.

Comment: I want to check whether FD is "writable" on the parent side, or in other words "is the reader side waiting for input?", and **not** that "is there any data in pipe which can be read". @mmmint, nonblocking IO is only for the second case as I know.

Comment: @julie-pelletier "check how many bytes are written" - I control only the parent process, it writes to pipe, not reads the written data.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're really trying to achieve by avoiding writing to that pipe but you should clarify that if you want an answer.  Normally, when a process writes to a pipe, all that matters is if that data is read or not.

Comment: "is the FD writable on the parent side" is NOT the same as "is the Reader side waiting for input". The parent can write until the pipe's buffer is full, then the reader needs to read before a write can succeeed. So what exactly do you want to check for (and maybe why)?